# Smartsheet API failure to recognize number values when creating row objects

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I need help adding numbers to a row update using the Smartsheet Python SDK.  I am attempting to update/add specific cell values programmatically via a Python script.  An example of the code I am using is:

```
import smartsheet

smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet(TokenString)

row = smartsheet.models.Row()
row.to_top = True
row.cells.append({
    'column_id': ColumnID,
    'value': x
})

action = smartsheet.Sheets.add_rows(SheetID, [row])
```

This seems to work just fine if the `'value'` I pass is a string.  However, when I pass a number it does nothing.  I have taken a look at the cell object created (simply printing it, which appears to be a JSON string) it shows `"value": null`.  Again, if I change this to a string the value shows just fine.

I have tried this with both integer and float values.  Both return null. Any help getting this to work would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this out myself I experienced the same thing. Only representing the value as a string did it enter into my sheet, otherwise it was a null/blank row. I have reported this as an issue on Github for the [Python SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/49). As a workaround I saw that working with the API directly rather than using the SDK does allow for this function.

Comment: Thanks @daveskull81.  Good to know I'm not the only one.  I'll probably go ahead and try doing this directly with the API.